# Was Rabbi Yehoshoua ben Hanania a member of Beth Shammai?

Tags: tannaim, beis-shammai, beis-hillel

He was a student of Yochanan Ben Zakkai. According to Bava Batra 134a, Yochanan Ben Zakkai was a Talmid of Beth Hillel but also a Talmid of Beth Shammai. This is why I wonder which House follow Rabbi Yehoshoua ben Hanania.

Also, Rabbi Eliezer was a talmid of Yochanan Ben Zakkai but followed beth Shammai (Yerushalmi Nazir 6:11). This is another reason why I wonder about the affiliation of Rabbi Yehoshoua.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%94) based on Gemara Chagiga 22b says that Rabbi Yehoshua ben Chananya followed Bais Hillel.

> רבי יהושע סבר היה מבית הלל ("בושני מדבריכם בית שמאי" - חגיגה כב:). לכן
>   הוא מיקל יותר, מתחשב במציאות, מעדיף את הכמות, את הבפועל , ומקרב גרים.